# trouble using time in VB.NET/PHP

Tags: php, vb.net

how I can get same result for using `echo time ;` in php in vb net
I try use `now` but it's not like `time` in php
example : if use `echo time ; in php = 1501791815082
but if I use`now` in vb net it's not same.
Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can access time in vb:

```
Dim theDate As DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
```

You can find more information at [DateTime.Now Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)